# How to allow only Hebrew letters in input for mobile page, and few more questions?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am little bit new to html and php programming so I wondered if there is a way to do the following things :

1. I have this input html code that should get a full name of a person.

   ```
   <form action="createName.php" method="post">
          <input  dir="rtl" name="fullname" type="text" placeholder="שם פרטי + שם משפחה" />           
       <button style="width: 100%;" class="button block green" type="submit"  id="login"> המשך      לאפליקצייה</button>
           </form>
   ```

This code supposed to be only for mobile devices, and I want to know if there is away to allow only Hebrew letters in this code ? I tried few things that didn't work maybe because its on mobile I am not sure, anyone have Ideas ?

2. Strange thing happens then A person start the typing inside the input, then the mobile keyboard shows up the input stays in the same position instead of going above the keyboard, The keyboard literally is above the input and the person can not see what he is typing inside, anyway to change it ?
3. The last question is less impotent because it does work but I would like to get your advice for the way it works, the thing is like this:
   There is log in using Facebook application to the website but the data given by Facebook is not enough for me and for this I wrote the code that I mentioned before because I need to have the full name of the person and in Facebook this name is not 100% correct because users usually add nicknames and stuff into their Facebook name. My code working like this, First person logs in with facebook account he is redirected back to main page, why the main page ? because there is a possibility that the user is not a new user and he entered his full name in his first log in, so in the main page the php script checking if this user have entered his full name and if not the script redirecting him to the input page there he is filling his full name. So what do you thing about the way it works ? Maybe there is a way to do is smarter ?

Thanks ahead :)

Comment: Ask one question per post, and make sure the question title corresponds to the specific question asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regular expressions in order to filter out any non Hebrew character.

```
<?php

function leaveOnlyHebrew($str)
{

    $strippedStr = trim($str);

    return trim(preg_replace('#[^א-ת ]#i', '', $strippedStr));
}

var_dump(leaveOnlyHebrew("azאב azטו"));//only hebrew and spaces

var_dump(leaveOnlyHebrew("azxc   gfh"));//empty

?>
```

Comment: Thank you I just did that looks like it working fine. Anyone have an answer about the second question ?

Comment: Hey regarding your Careers question, http://meta.stackexchange.com/ is indeed the correct place, however it is being used for other things so tagging it properly is critical. Please ask again, this time tagging properly and add a screenshot of the problem (e.g. of the error you get) and it would be fine. People simply thought you talk about resume in general, hence the downvotes you got initially.